# Searching an item in an ObservableArrayList

Tags: android, android-databinding

I had previously used the search in normal ArrayList, it worked well. Now , I am using DataBinding Library, and using ObservableArrayList in RecyclerView. But, when I use the same logic, it doesn't return the correct result.

Here is my code in the adapter to search an item.

```
public void filter(String text) {
        list.clear();
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            list.addAll(listCopy);
        } else {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            for (AnswerPOJO item : listCopy) {
                if (item.getAnswerdata().getAnswer_key().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                    list.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"it doesn't return the correct result."` and what it returns instead?

Comment: The list becomes empty

Comment: you have problem with your data then - both `ObservableArrayList` and `ArrayList` work the same when it comes to `java.util.List` interface

Comment: Initially, the data is present. When I start Typing in the searchbox, the list becomes empty.

Comment: what you see if you run: https://pastebin.com/raw/TmfAvDdZ ? `ObservableArrayList` works just fine: you have problem with your data

Comment: It was some logical error. I was adding the list in the constructor. When during the api call it was blank. and after api response, the main list was populated, but not the copied List. That is why, it was coming empty. So, I created a method to add list to adapter, and called it when I received the api response.

Comment: thats why i said that `"you have problem with your data"`